# On-the-fly conversion of MPEG files on MonoTouch

Tags: .net, mono, ffmpeg, xamarin.ios, mpeg

I have an iPhone application that uses small MPEG movies showing hand signs in the Dutch Sign Language. I get the movies from the [Gebarencentrum](http://www.gebarencentrum.nl), with their permission. But they are all in the old MPEG-1 format, and the iPhone won't play that. The allowed me to convert a couple of hunderd of the movies in batch and put them on my own website, but they won't let me do that with all 6000 movies. So I need to convert the movie from MPEG-1 to MP4 after getting it from their server to my iPhone.
I have searched for libraries like ffmpeg, but none if it is already ported to Mono. Maybe I do not have to port ffmpeg to .NET/Mono since I can P/Invoke to the ffmpeg library. But can I install ffmpeg on my iPhone and if so, how?

I'm open to any ideas.

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 3):

Compile ffmpeg as a library in XCode and then link it to your program:
http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Interop/Consuming_3rd_Party_ObjC_Libraries

Since applications can only statically link on the iPhone, instead of using P/Invoke over a shared library name, like this:

[DllImport ("ffmpeg.so")]
extern static int ffmpeg_init ();

You need to use the __Internal target:

[DllImport ("__Internal")]
extern static int ffmpeg_init ();

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I'm still working on this, every now and then, and I find it really hard. I found another article on the same wiki that explains it a bit more: http://wiki.monotouch.net/HowTo/Interop/Interopping_with_Open_Source_Text-to-Speech_%28TTS%29_C_libraries__for_iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

isnt using ffmpeg to convert mpeg-1 to a playable very mp4(v) slowww on the iPhone?
or is this a good way forward?

Comment: Hi Toni, it probably was'nt the brightest idea, but I had no choice, given the constraints from the owner of the videos. The project is off now, since they completely withdraw their permission to use the videos.